# Cannot enable Secure boot on Gigabyte H61M-DS2

Tags: windows-10, bios, bootable-media, secure-boot

Trying to help a friend do a fresh install of Windows, but the bootable USB isn't even listed in the BIOS. I realized that Secure Boot is currently disabled, and assume this is the issue. However Secure Boot isn't just an option that I see. It's just a status indicator at the bottom saying it's disabled. Could really use some help here.

Comment: It sounds like CSM is enabled.  Secure Boot is incompatible with CSM.

Comment: Funny thing is, I don't even see anything in here about CSM mode. I tried setting Boot Mode Selection and Storage Boot Option Control to UEFI Only, but that doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: Something listing “UEFI only” is a good sign, it means, your system must support UEFI mode, so I am starting to suspect the problem is the installation media.

Comment: Remade the USB a couple of times now. I tried looking up the board and revision, but info seems to be incorrect even on the manufacturers site. I'm now going to try booting through Advanced Startup on the current Windows install. The plan was to re-install Windows on the SSD. Luckily the original Windows install is still on the old HDD.

Comment: Reset and installing from an installation media will result in the same exact end goal by the way

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to keep the old install for now, so he can transfer over some files before formatting the old drive. EDIT: it appears that even in the advanced startup menu, the option for booting from a secondary device is missing.

Comment: I guess the main goal here is to just get a new Windows install on the SSD, while keeping the old install on the HDD temporarily to copy over files to the new install. I don't care the method. Whatever works works.

Comment: So I'm even more confused now. It seems like the BIOS just doesn't detect USB at all for some reason. Q-Flash doesn't even detect the connected USB with the BIOS update on it.

Comment: How exactly are you burning the ISO? If *not* using the official Media Creation tool (Microsoft) there are very few options that actually work. Rufus does but pay attention to the options before "burning" or you may end up with something that only boot in BIOS or Legacy mode (BTW, that motherboard has UEFI, not BIOS, like pretty much anything since 2012!)

Comment: Tried using Media Creation Tool, and Rufus to burn the ISO. What is odd though, is that the BIOS won't even detect the USB when trying to update BIOS. I know I shouldn't but I use the term BIOS and UEFI interchangeably. The manual for this exact revision of the board seems missing too. Gigabyte's site seems to be incorrect about the board. According to Gigabyte's site, the board we have here is somehow a mix of multiple revisions they have. But then I found the board on Aorus' site. This site has the correct info, but no manual.